# Python multiline regex with org-mode files

Tags: python, regex, org-mode

Using regex, I would like to extract certain parts from an Emacs org mode file, which are simple text files. Entries in these org files start with `*` and sometimes these entries do have properties. A brief example can be found below:

```
import re

orgfiletest = """
* headline 0
* headline 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :KEY: lala
  :END:
* headline 2
* headline 3
  :PROPERTIES:
  :KEY: lblb
  :END:
"""
```

I would like to extract all entries that do have properties; the extracted entries should include these properties. So, I would like to receive the following pieces of text:

```
* headline 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :KEY: lala
  :END:
```

and

```
* headline 3
  :PROPERTIES:
  :KEY: lblb
  :END:
```

I started with something like this

```
re.findall(r"\*.*\s:END:", orgfiletest, re.DOTALL)
```

But this also includes `headline 0` and `headline 2`, which do not have any properties. My next attempt was to utilize look arounds but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated!

**Update / Solution that works for me:**

Thanks to everyone who helped me finding a solution! For future reference I included an updated MWE and the regex that works for me:

```
import re
orgfiletest = """
* headline 0
  more text 
* headline 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :KEY: lala
  :END:
* headline foo 2
** bar 3
  :PROPERTIES:
  :KEY: lblb
  :FOOBAR: lblb
  :END:
* new headline
  more text
"""

re.findall(r"^\*+ .+[\r\n](?:(?!\*)\s*:.+[\r\n]?)+", orgfiletest, re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities including non-regex solutions.
As you have specifically asked for one though:

```
^\*\ headline\ \d+[\r\n] # look for "* headline digit(s) and newline
(?:(?!\*).+[\r\n]?)+     # followed by NOT a newline at the beginning
                         # ... anything else including newlines afterwards
                         # ... at least once
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/TfyRs0/1/) (and mind the modifiers `x` and `m`!)

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'''
            ^\*\ headline\ \d+[\r\n] 
            (?:(?!\*).+[\r\n]?)+
            ''', re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

print(rx.findall(orgfiletest))
```

---

A **non-regex** way could be (using [**`itertools`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)):

```
from itertools import groupby

result = {}; key = None
for k, v in groupby(
        orgfiletest.split("\n"), 
        lambda line: line.startswith('* headline')):
    if k:
        item = list(v)
        key = item[len(item)-1]
    elif key is not None:
        result[key] = list(v)

print(result)
# {'* headline 1': ['  :PROPERTIES:', '  :KEY: lala', '  :END:'], '* headline 3': ['  :PROPERTIES:', '  :KEY: lblb', '  :END:', '']}
```

This has the downside that lines starting with e.g. `* headline abc` or `* headliner***` would be used as well. To be honest, I'd go for the `regex` solution here.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks so much! Just out of curiosity, what are other  possibilities including non-regex solutions?

Comment: @BerndWeiss: Sorry, was away. Updated the answer and added a non-regex solution.

Comment: Again, thanks so much for your help! I should have emphasized, though, that in headlines other words than "headline" can be found. I've updated my question with a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do it like this. Only matches rec's containing *PROPERTIES*

`(?ms)^\*(?:(?!^\*).)*?PROPERTIES(?:(?!^\*).)*`

https://regex101.com/r/oZcos0/1

Explained

```
 (?ms)                 # Inline modifiers:  Multi-line, Dot-all
 ^ \*                  # Start record: BOL plus *
 (?:                   # Minimal matching
      (?! ^ \* )            # Not a new record
      . 
 )*?
 PROPERTIES            # Up to prop
 (?:                   # Max matching up to begin new record
      (?! ^ \* )            # Not a new record
      . 
 )*
```

Answer (score 1):

An attempt at making a readable regex:

```
^\*\sheadline(?:(?!^\*\sheadline).)*:END:$
```

`^\*\sheadline` -> the item is known to start like this.

`(?:(?!^\*\sheadline).)*` -> match anything as long as it doesn't include how we know a new item starts.

`:END:$` -> it includes a known end statement at the end of a line.

[Working demo.](https://regex101.com/r/xGwWFt/1)